# Swift : [NSDictionary]()

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have data stored in a `[NSDictionary]()` here is how I add the data:

```
var usedObjectDictionaries = [NSDictionary]()

for firstUseItem in useItemsInFirstObject {
        let dict = firstUseItem.toDictionary()
        usedObjectDictionaries.append(dict)
    }
```

And the `[NSDictionary]()` if printed out looks like this:

[image]

What I need to do is reach the value of the `ActivityReference1` in the `[NSDictionary]()`. 
Meaning , how can I get to the `Job`.

Comment: You have several 'ActivityReference1', which one do you want to reach? The 1st one? Each one?

Comment: The first one, they will all have the same value, so it does not really matter, but preferably the first one @MarieDm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for item in usedObjectDictionaries {
    print(item["ActivityReference1"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first one:

```
usedObjectDictionaries[0]["ActivityReference1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

@MarieDM's answer of using array indexing will work, but it will crash if the array is empty.

You could also use

```
if let activity = userObjectDictionaries.first["ActivityReference1"] {
    //here "activity" contains the entry from the first entry
} else {
    //This code will execute 
    //if there are no entries in userObjectDictionaries
}
```